# Firestore Rules: Making documents in a collection and all subcollections follow the same rule

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm making a structure that looks something like this:

```
users
  user1
  user2
  user3
group
  group1
  group2
  group3
     subcollections1
        subdoc11
        subdoc12
     subcollections2
        subdoc21
        subdoc22
```

So explaining it, I have a users collection and group collection. All users must be part of one and only one group. A group has a 'members' field which I check if the user is a member or not.

So my rules are something like this for now.

```
match /groups/{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if resource.data.users[request.auth.uid] != null;
}
```

My question is, would it accurately check if user is in **group1->doc-'members'** even when writing to a subcollection or would it check in **group1->doc->subcollection->doc-'members'** in that case?

Because the members list is only in the groups collection but not in the subcollection so the second situation is not wanted.

Comment: What happens when you test the rule on your own?  I don't think it will work, but honestly, this is something you can find out for yourself pretty easily.

Comment: @DougStevenson I'm about to test it myself, but honestly, it gives me the impression that this should be achieved by something like: 
When it's the group's document, read in resource.data
When it's subcollection, use get() function to get the group's doc.

This question was hoping that someone knowledgeable could provide me a confirmation or suggestion.

Comment: The purpose of Stack Overflow is to help people with code that isn't working the way they expect (provided debugging details), not to predict if some code will work as expected.  I suggest reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I haven't actually tried, the `resource.data` variable is a refernce to the document being accessed. So if the path accesses the document `/groups/group3/subcollections1/subdoc11` that would be the document referenced by `resource.data`. Therefore I think you're rule won't work as expected.

Regarding how to implement the desired behavior, note that it's best to define Firestore rules at the most granular level. This would prevent to accidentally grant access when a stricter rule ought to be applied but instead a wider rule is applied. I would suggest something alike this:

```
match /groups/{groupId} {
  allow read, write: if resource.data.users[request.auth.uid] != null;
}

match /groups/{groupId}/{subcollection}/{documentId} {
  allow read, write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/$(groupId)).data.users[request.auth.uid] != null
}
```

For further reference check this pages about [how rules work](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-language) and [sample rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics).

Comment: That's going to give me an extra reading right? I don't actually mind it, but I think I might make it less strict here. Anyway, I don't want to decrease security, but I need to think it through first. Thanks

Comment: @LucasNantes Yes, the second rule implies an additional read.